# With the "user_status" Facebook permission, can I make an app to show the user their personality?

Tags: facebook, facebook-permissions

I have an app that analyzes text comments and figures out the personality out of it. I'd like to integrate Facebook in it, but when checking the *user_status* permission, I read:

- (OK) Provide creative content from status updates.
- (OK) Provide value to the user by visibly analyzing the content of their past statuses.
- (Not OK) Non-visible use of this data such as sentiment analysis or
  guarding against spam bots.

The app will show the user their personality. It analyzes the content of their past statuses and provide value to the person, they know something more about their personality and, depending on which category they fall, they will see a picture and a brief description of it.

I'm not sure about the last point, does my work count as doing "sentiment analysis"? The use of this data is completely shown to the user.

I was wondering this because I couldn't find any app that do this after the recent changes of last April in Facebook.

Since to request the permission Facebook wants to see everything in action, knowing this is not permitted at all in advance will save me some coding.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't work at Facebook so I have no idea what they *mean* by that last point...However, the "non-visible" side of it may refer to the fact that the user doesn't actually see what data you are using - you're just using *all* comments/posts/etc... In addition, the `sentiment` part of it may refer to the "logic" you choose to use in your analysis... The meaning of "sentiment" in this case would be: `"a view of or attitude toward a situation or event; an opinion."` - it is your applications *opinion* of the users personality.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion anyway! Yeah it doesn't seem too easy contacting them and apparently they launched facebook.stackoverflow.com... not sure how useful it is.

Comment: That is just a url that redirects to a Facebook tag filter... It's still the same site... Unfortunately it's never been easy to get in contact directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to properly answer my own question, with the answer coming from another website, but I got a very kind feedback from David Doyle on the "Facebook Developer Community" group on Facebook.

> We see a lot of apps that do or claim to do similar to what you're looking for. Permissions can be approved in these cases if the content is clearly influenced by the information a permission provides, is clearly visible to people using the app and results vary based on the information provided.
>
> Where some apps might fall down with requests like this is claiming "the answer is custom based on your user_status" but in reality, the answers are always the same - or there's a core set of answers that are rotated and the information provided from login are never used in the app.
>
> Hope this makes things a bit clearer!

Then he added

> What I mean by clear visibility is that if I'm a person signing into your app I should know *why* you're asking me for user_status.
>
> When I get my result, I should know *how* my status information contributed to it.

Permalink to the discussion, if you're in the Facebook group: [link](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/946933955350119/)

Comment: So it looks like your app would be okay as long as it is not fake and is visible to the user. Thanks for sharing your answer. I'm interested in which sentiment analysis library or API you are using. I also thought of doing something similar to your app that charts their sentiment status over time on a graph. I was thinking about using the free sentiment analysis API provided by Twinword API. Which one are you currently using?

Comment: We had a psychology researcher to do the engine :-) I'm just in charge of the development for the website/app and making sure the social connections are possible.

Yeah I think as long as the analysis is "real", everything'll be ok. I'm shocked then that FiveLabs didn't port their work to the new API, they were doing a great job.

I guess there are also a lot of those apps that pretend to tell you your personality, but in reality they just pick a random sentence from a pool of generic ones.

Comment: Sounds like you have a solid thing going. Where can I read more about your project and/or progress. Would love to learn more! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Jack Did you get the validation and how is it advancing ! I'm verious curious of a real app that is not a scam !

Comment: Hi @Elyx0 yes I got the permission reviewed and granted by Facebook. Unfortunately I can't talk too much of the app itself :-(
But it's nothing too special, here's what I understood looking at the engine's code: the personality recognition engine was created getting thousands of text comments of people with a known personality mapped in OCEAN values. From that you can link some similarities in how someone writes to a personality trait.

The owner of the code was planning of releasing it under CC license or similar if I recall correctly, I'll make sure to update this thread whenever it happens!